# InstallContext isPush method cause Install Package Failed

Tags: apex, managed-package, postinstall

In my managed package, I create a PostInstall class, in onInstall method, I have follow code:

```
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
    if (context.isPush()) {
    }
```

When install package, I got email said Failed. After research I comment these code. Re-create a package again. This time I can Install Package.

May I ask why?

Comment: Are you saying an empty if statement caused the failure, or did you have some code within the if statement that you commented out?

Comment: @PhilW, yes, I'm saying an empty if statement caused this failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We contract Salesforce Support, this is a Salesforce issue, and they fixed it now.